# BlackBerry Java CodeCompletion is missing

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm currently developing a little BlackBerry App and after setting up Eclipse (Plugin v1.3, SDK6.0) I noticed that I don't have any code completion!

Is there any configuration necessary to make this work? Coding without code completion is kind of annoying ;)

Here a screenshot of an example where i would need a code completion:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of where you expect code completion?   And what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: As you can see in the edited version above, i instantiated CustomTextField and would like to get a code completion for "myFie". Pressing CTRL+SPACE doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already solved the problem!

The problem were the Content Assist Advanced Settings. At first i hadn't "Java Proposal" checked, but after checking this it works perfectly.

Thank you guys for your comments.

[image]

Comment: I had to check Java Type Proposals to fix my issue, but your answer got me there!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install in a new directory and not over a previous Eclipse directory. This happened to me as well when I tried to install into a previous Eclipse directory. RIM build 1.3.0 with Eclipse Platform Version: 3.6.1 Build id: M20100909-0800.